# Why wouldn't React Router work with <Switch>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning React router, tried to build a pretty basic application like this `Home.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import About from '../pages/About';
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {

    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/about-us">ABOUT US</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about-us">
                        <About />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Then in `index.js` render `Home` page:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Problem is, `Home` wouldn't render in localhost:3000, terminal showed `Compiled successfully!` but when loading localhost:3000, it just spins forever with nothing rendered. However, if I remove the  element it rendered. Folder structure set like this:

```
src
--pages
----About.js
----Home.js
index.js
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created yourself an infinite loop from what it looks like. Your index.js returns your Home component, which then returns the Navbar, which has a router, which then returns the Home component, which then repeats that cycle over and over again.

This is the approach I would take, which will show the Navbar on both the about and home page, and will only show one of the pages at a time based on the current route.

```js
// Navbar.js

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/about-us">ABOUT US</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

```js
// Layout.js

import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import About from '../pages/About';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar />

            <Switch>
                <Route path="/about-us">
                    <About />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    <Home />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Layout />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
src
--components
----Navbar.js
----Layout.js
--pages
----About.js
----Home.js
index.js
```

Comment: What I actually wanted was `Home.js` as homepage, which uses `Navbar.js` as a component, and set up Router in `Navbar.js` cause that's where routing happens. `Home.js` is directly rendered in `index.js`. Can you edit your answer based on this?

Comment: You can't use Navbar within Home.js and also have your router done inside of Navbar. This will cause the infinite loop you are experiencing. You will need to extract your router and use it elsewhere. I can show you the approach I take, if that'll help.

Comment: How can I avoid the loop if I want to include `Navbar` component in `Home`, but also route to `Home` page in `Navbar`? Can't see how to avoid the infinite loop

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect a possible approach.